# React fetch doesn't display value from nested object

Tags: reactjs

I have a problem with getting value from nestle object. I want to get value name from studySets (this is a nested object in object user). The program knows that it is an object but it can't display value (show two dots because, in the database, it is two user objects). I have added a screenshot with the response. Please tell me where is the problem.

[image: Screen with response]

> WordSet.js

```
export class WordSet extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      users: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(URL)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => {
        this.setState({ users: json });
      });
  }

  render() {
    const { users } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {users.map((user) => (
            <li key={user.id}>{user.studySets.name}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default WordSet;
```

Comment: try `{user.studySets[0].name}` in the `<li>`

Comment: Do you always want to get the data of the first user alone?

Comment: Yes. What I should do when I don't want get the data of the first user alone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok basically you are treating the studySets as object which is rather an array. so either you have to loop over the studySets array as well or if you always want the data of the first user then do something like this as I mentioned in the comment:

```
{user.studySets[0].name}
```

in the

```
<li>
```